# Coroutine function stops at WaitForSeconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My coroutine funtion works only one time. The  `_isPaused` variable is `true`. Can't find out what I did wrong.

```
IEnumerator Movement() 
{
    while (_isPaused) // I checked, it's true
    {  
        Debug.Log("Some action");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.8f);
    }
}

void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P)) 
    {
        StartCoroutine(Movement());
    }
}
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/0z7NxMZY) is the complete code:

Comment: there are better ways to do movement.

Comment: @Lestat give some examples, please.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that piece of code. Probably there are some other errors that cause trouble. Did you check your debug log?

Comment: @oRole yes, checked. No errors, warnings. It's stops on yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.8f); and doesn't go further. _isPaused stays true

Comment: @LarsTech I changed to StartCoroutine(Movement()) (it's I tried another ways to make it work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your code:

```
while (_isPaused) 
{  
    Debug.Log("Some action");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.8f);
}
```

Your `while` loop will pause when it reaches the `WaitForSeconds`. It will pause because you're setting `Time.timeScale` to `0` somewhere in the code when "P" is pressed. This behavior is normal. It's made so that you can pause your coroutine functions with `Time.timeScale`. It will upause and continue to run as soon as you set `Time.timeScale` back to `1`.

---

If you do not want  `Time.timeScale` to pause your coroutine function when you're waiting with `WaitForSeconds` then use `WaitForSecondsRealtime` instead of `WaitForSeconds`.

```
while (_isPaused) 
{
    Debug.Log("Some action");
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(0.8f);
}
```

---

This is because `WaitForSeconds` is implemented with `Time.deltaTime` or a similar property which also becomes `0` when `Time.timeScale` is set to `0` causing the timer to pause while `WaitForSecondsRealtime` is implemented with `Time.realtimeSinceStartup` which is not affected by `Time.timeScale` at all.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. Didn't know that Time.timeScale has effect also on WaitForSeconds.

Comment: Yup and that's why people use it to pause games. It also affects `Time.deltaTime` too. You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Without the whole code of the program, it is hard to tell what is wrong. I suggest you test the coroutine using **true**

```
IEnumerator Movement()
    {
        while (true) 
        {
            Debug.Log("Some action");
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.8f);
        }
    }
```

instead of using the **_isPause** field.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but it didn't work. https://pastebin.com/0z7NxMZY here's the whole code